# Не отрабатывает formit hooks

Tags: cms, modx, revo

работаю в modx revo, не знаю в чем проблема, вывожу на страницы неподтвержденные комментарии (от 1 до 100) вот так

```
<div class="col-md-4">
<form  method="POST" action="">
<input type="hidden" name="zayavka_id" value="[[+zayavka_id]]"/>
  <div class="text_review">

        <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-2 rev_img_u">
    <img src="[[+usr:userinfo=`photo`:phpthumbon=`wp=50&hp=50&wl=50&hl=50&zc=1`]]"/>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-9 col-md-10 name_city_block">
    <span class="rev_name_u">[[+usr::userinfo=`fullname`:is=``:then=`[[+usr::userinfo=`username`]]`:else=`[[+usr::userinfo=`fullname`]]`]]</span>

    <span class="rev_city_u">г.[[+usr::userinfo=`city`]]</span>
  </div>
      <!--<div class="col"><span></span><input id="switch1" class="switch" name="switch1" type="checkbox" /><span></span></div>-->

    <p class="col-xs-12">[[+text:ellipsis=`300`]]</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">
      <span class="rev_date_u" style="top: 0px;
      position: absolute;
      right: 0px;">[[dateAgo? &input=`[[+createdate]]`
  ]]</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">
      <span class="like_d" style="top: 0px;">
    [[+star:is=`1`:then=`<div class="tgl-but-good">Хорошо</div>`:else=`<div class="tgl-but-bad">Плохо</div>`]]  
        </span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">
      <button name="steljevraagsubmit[[+zayavka_id]]" type="submit">Опубликовать</button>
  </div>

  </form>
</div>
  [[!Formit? &hooks=`moderOtz` &formFields=`zayavka_id` &submitVar=`steljevraagsubmit[[+zayavka_id]]` ]]
```

при нажатии на сабмит должен срабатывать хук `moderOtz`
вот содержимое

```
<?php
$zayavka_id=$hook->getValue('zayavka_id');
return print_r($zayavka_id);
```

страница перегружается и все, ничего не показывает

Comment: `return print_r($zayavka_id);`
это не сработает. используй `modx->log`

Comment: решил проблему, спасибо